# Javascript - how do i remove the record from this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do i remove the Bob from this array and refresh the array key so that Charlie key becomes 0 not 1 after removing Bob?

```
//Insert: OK
var cars = [];
cars[cars.length] ="Bob";
cars[cars.length] ="Charlie";
cars[cars.length] ="Laura";
console.log( cars );

//Update: OK

function Update(input, upgrade) {
  for(var key in cars) {
    if(cars[key]===input) {
      cars[key] = upgrade;
    }
  }
}
Update("Bob", "Bob-sleeping");
console.log( cars );

// Now removing Bob-sleeping from the array which should show Charlie and Laura
```

Comment: The entire `Update` part of the code above is unrelated to the question, right? Because it's changing the entry, not removing it.

Comment: Correct, just matching the value there.

Comment: It would make much more sense to remove irrelevant code and just show what you want to remove.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`splice`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.12):

```
cars.splice(0, 1);
```

`0` is the index at which to remove the entry, `1` is how many entries to remove.

```js
"use strict";
var cars = [];
cars[cars.length] ="Bob";
cars[cars.length] ="Charlie";
cars[cars.length] ="Laura";

display("Before: " + cars.join(", "));

cars.splice(0, 1);

display("After: " + cars.join(", "));

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

If you need to find out the index, on even vaguely modern browsers you can use `indexOf` (which can be shimmed on really old ones). So if you're starting with `"Bob-sleeping"`, then:

```
var index = cars.indexOf("Bob-sleeping");
if (index !== -1) {
    cars.splice(index, 1);
}
```

```js
"use strict";
var cars = [];
cars[cars.length] ="Bob";
cars[cars.length] ="Charlie";
cars[cars.length] ="Laura";

display("Before: " + cars.join(", "));

var index = cars.indexOf("Bob"); // Or "Bob-sleeping", if you've `Update`d
if (index !== -1) {
  cars.splice(index, 1);
}


display("After: " + cars.join(", "));

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```